# Android Dynamic Features not in .apk

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

My project contains a dynamic feature called `feature_login`

[image]

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I configured feature as `included` and NOT `on demand`.

```
<manifest ...>
    <dist:module
            dist:onDemand="false" dist:title="@string/title_feature_login">
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true"/>
    </dist:module>
</manifest>
```

So I assumed that the given feature will be included in the .apk file by default. But when I am generating .apk using Android Studio

[image]

seems that it doesn't contain that feature as the app is crashing as soon as I am pressing on the button which starts the feature.

But the app works when I am running it from the Android Studio on the Emulator using `Run` button.

## Question

1. Are dynamic features good for a use case like Login?
2. How I can build debug app which contains dynamic feature?
3. Are dynamic features included in the .apk if `dist:onDemand="false"` and `dist:fusing dist:include="true"`?
4. Are dynamic features good for case when you want to have separate modules (ex. Login, Profile Details, etc) or better to use library module?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Are dynamic features good for a use case like Login?

If you can decouple dependencies from the rest of your app while still using login, sure.

> 2. How I can build debug app which contains dynamic feature?

Either through the app bundle flow using [bundletool](http://github.com/google/bundletool) or using Android Studio.
You can also use `./gradlew assemble` and then `adb install-multiple` with all relevant debug apks.

> 3. Are dynamic features included in the .apk if `dist:onDemand="false"` and `dist:fusing dist:include="true"`?

No. The fusing flag is relevant for .aab. APK fusing is honored when the target device runs on API < 21.

> 4. Are dynamic features good for case when you want to have separate modules (ex. Login, Profile Details, etc) or better to use library module?

I recommend using dynamic feature modules for user facing features. So e.g. Profile, Login, Shopping Cart, PremiumWhatever can be good starting points.
There are advanced use cases for saving more on device space, but these rely on delayed delivery via [on demand](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery/on-demand-delivery) or [conditional delivery](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery/conditional-delivery).

For more information I recommend taking a look at the [Plaid](https://github.com/android/plaid) sample app or watching one of [the presentations on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ox_MFgxeNY0).

Answer (score 1):

the dynamic feature needs to use with [app-bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/), not `APKs`.

When you debug the app, you could include the dynamic feature by modifying your existing `run/debug configuration`.

Firstly, select your desired Android App configuration, then 
under dynamic features to deploy in the **General tab**, check the box next to each dynamic feature module you want to include when deploying
your app.

Comment: Have you tried what you wrote or just copy-pasted it from somewhere and expect it to work?! OP is asking about generating .apk not run configurations

Answer (score 0):

If Build APKs option would be selected, then it will create multiple Apks same as the number of dynamic features into your app.

But it seems the requirement is to create a single APK having all the dynamic features, so to do that

**a) For debug builds :**

Edit Configuration -> General  -> (Look for dynamic features to deploy option) -> Select all the dynamic features to include them into the build -> Apply -> OK

**b) For release builds :**

Generate the signed App Bundle and follow below steps:

i) Download the Bundle tool from the below link :
https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases/download/1.5.0/bundletool-all-1.5.0.jar

ii) execute the below command in the terminal or android studio terminal in the same directory of above bundle too

```
java -jar bundletool-all-1.5.0.jar build-apks --bundle {path/of/yours/.aab} --output {output/path}/name-of-output.apks --ks <key-path> --key-pass pass:{key-password} --ks-key-alias {key-alias}
--ks-pass pass:{key-alias-password} --overwrite --mode=universal
```

Replace {} strings with your own values, after executing above command it will create a univeral .apks file. (Note it is .apks , not .apk)

iii) To install .apks into the device:

```
adb install -r <output/path>/name-of-output.apks
```

Hope it would help.